# Efficiency of different Processors and GPUs

Tags: rendering

I don't really know where I should ask this, so I decided to come here.
I want to send multiple 3D files to several computers to render, and for that I need to approximately determine when each system will finish the render operation (I know the stats of the computers).
My question is, based on any information you could get from a system (CPU, GPU, OS, ...),
is it possible to determine (approximately) when the system will be done rendering a project?
(Assume we are talking about a specific software and project so that we can compare the cmputers).

**Update:**
I'm looking for something like FLOPS, but I don't know how that would work in terms of rendering things.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a word: Yes. But the question is so general and vague that it is difficult to say more then that, other then to speculate which is discourage here. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Thanks for responding.Okay, I'll try to give an example.Suppose I have a known 3D software and a specific file, could I find out how faster one computer would perform in rendering this file than another computer? Let's say my computer has a 1 core CPU and it renders this file in an hour, could I approximate how long it would take to render this file in a computer with 4 cores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is: it depends.

If the software is a black box that you have no control over then the best you will be able to do is measure wall clock run time on the host systems. That will give you general numbers in terms of wall clock time and is the most common way to gather this type of performance data. But will be affected by other processes running on the systems and a host of other variables. Repeated runs generally give better info.

Making assumptions about CPU count isn't a good measure of expected performance because it depends heavily on the software. Will it utilize extra CPU's, will it have good cache coherency?

You would be better off just gathering hardware data and comparing expected performance.

From what you have describe doing both may be about as good as you will get. That is gather hardware data about the system, CPU, GPU, memory, etc. Run the render process as often as you can, such as render the same file 100 times in a loop measure how long it takes for each render operation, and take the average. Then use the combined info to make generalizations about similar hardware configurations.

I've done this technique on server farms that had thousands of systems, all with similar hardware and gotten wildly different results. Measuring performance accurately is tricky business.